# How can I get OpenAI API for flutter working from China?

Tags: flutter, vpn, openai-api

I am building a flutter app using the [dart_openai](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_openai) package and the recommended [envied](https://pub.dev/packages/envied) package to obsure the OpenAI API key.

Note, as I am in China, I am also using a VPN (Astrill) - and the API works smooth & connects fast on the simulator on my Mac.

However, when I build an android app to a real phone I get this error message "Failed host lookup: 'api.openai.com'.

My android real phone has Astrill VPN too. I also had my friend try the app in Australia (no need for VPN) and the connection error remained. So I am stumped.

So wondering if anyone else had a similar issue with the OpenAI API not connecting on a real device, and was able to solve it?

Here is a basic code snippet that works on the simulator:

```
void main() async {
  OpenAI.apiKey = Env.apiKey;
  runApp(const TestGPT());
}

class TestGPT extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestGPT({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestGPT> createState() => _TestGPTState();
}

class _TestGPTState extends State<TestGPT> {
  late final openAIFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    openAIFuture = testOpenAI();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder<OpenAIChatCompletionModel>(
          future: openAIFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                    'success ${snapshot.data!.choices.first.message.content}'),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                    'failed ${snapshot.error.toString()}'),
              );
            }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }),
    );
  }
}

Future<OpenAIChatCompletionModel> testOpenAI() async {
  return await OpenAI.instance.chat.create(
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages: [
      OpenAIChatCompletionChoiceMessageModel(
        content: "What is 2 + 5 ?",
        role: OpenAIChatMessageRole.user,
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```